# why this is not connecting to flipper although i have install Redux Debugger

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, flipper

**Package I have install**
1."react-native-flipper": "^0.181.0",
2."redux-flipper": "^2.0.2",

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import userReducer from '../redux/userSlice';

const createDebugger = require('redux-flipper').default;

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },

  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    __DEV__
      ? getDefaultMiddleware({
          serializableCheck: true,
        })
          .concat(createDebugger())
          .concat(thunkMiddleware)
      : getDefaultMiddleware({
          serializableCheck: false,
        })
          .concat(createDebugger())
          .concat(thunkMiddleware),
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch;
```

**I have no idea why this is not running. if anyone has idea then please let me know**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to push `createDebugger` in middleware.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRRFx.png)

Comment: can you help me write my code so I can understand it quickly?

Comment: It like as 
```
middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => {
    const middlewares = getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER]
      }
    });

    middlewares.push(sagaMiddleware);

    if (__DEV__ && !process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID) {
      const createDebugger = require('redux-flipper').default;
      middlewares.push(createDebugger());
    }

    return middlewares;
  }
```